# Correct command for root access in Android

Tags: java, android, roottools

I have next example:

```
RootTools.isRootAvailable()
Command command = new Command(0, "echo this is a command", "echo this is another command");
try {
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
}catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i don't know what to write to *"echo this is a command", "echo this is another command*" and how to apply it for my folder without permission. Maybe you know? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This placeholder `this is a command` should be replaced with bash code.** 

You (most likely, assuming it's not specific to Android) could run it in a Linux terminal.

The placholder `echo this is a command` is a perfectly valid command, and will simply *echo*, or print the text.

Some other command you could run are:

1. `cp` copy file
2. `mv` move file
3. `touch` create an empty file